# Rsync doesn't recognize charset

Tags: rsync

When i am trying to synchronize my clent PC with server i get an error.

```
rsync -rv -p 2222 --progress --delete-before --ignore-existing andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/Книги/ /media/Maindata/Книги
```

output is like this:

```
Unexpected remote arg: andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/\#320\#232\#320\#275\#320\#270\#320\#263\#320\#270/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
```

locale of server and client as well:

```
LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_UA.UTF-8
```

Is here anyone way to solve my problem except of rename directories(ru -> en)?

Comment: Does `LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8 rsync ...` work?

Comment: No, it's dont work. Same error appears

Comment: Does your server accept `LC_*` variables from client? Do you have `AcceptEnv LC_*` in `sshd_config`?

Comment: Yes, it is.
`# Allow client to pass locale environment variables`
`AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`

Answer (score 0):

I dug out in wrong place. After experiments with locale i suddenly detected - this error appear before resolving a host.
Helped  this: **-e "ssh -p 2222"**.

```
rsync -rv -e "ssh -p 2222" --progress --delete-before --ignore-existing --dry-run andrew@192.168.0.101:/media/Maindata/Книги/ /media/Maindata/Книги/
```

It's successfully resolve remote source.